# VBA Recordset with varying records

Tags: excel, vba

I have a slimple loop code that pulls data from an SQL query. The SQL query itself only pull back Top 5 records. However depending on which account I'm looking at I won't always get 5 records sometimes its just one or two. I was wondering how I can get the code to just loop through what is there without erroring when it can't find row 3,4 or 5?

Thanks in advance

```
For i = 0 To 4

    Sheets("Exposures").Range("F36").Offset(i, 0).Value = rst2.Fields("Country")
    Sheets("Exposures").Range("I36").Offset(i, 0).Value = rst2.Fields("Value")
    rst2.MoveNext

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop, but only while there are available rows:

```
do while not rst2.EOF

  ...

  i = i + 1
  rst2.MoveNext
loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` Method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240(v=office.15).aspx).
Dynamic, and probably faster than a loop.
I think I remember it has a bug if you have very large (above 2KB) text fields however. If it's not your case, go for it.

```
Sheets("Exposures").Range("I36").CopyFromRecordset rst2
```